# Need to map json to list

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have register variable with below json as value and need to extract name and dn from this JSON to list. tried different options using set_fact without any luck.

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "status": -1,
        "imdata": [
            {
                "fabricNode": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "status": "",
                        "dn": "topology/pod-1/node-1",
                        "name": "NOQCJALAB1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "fabricNode": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "status": "",
                        "dn": "topology/pod-1/node-1",
                        "name": "NOQCJALAB2"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "totalCount": 2,
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    },
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extraneous calls to `map('from_json')` because the object is already a `dict`

```
- set_fact:
    node_names: >-
      {{ (nodes.stdout | from_json).data
      | map(attribute='fabnode')
      | map(attribute='attributes')
      | map(attribute='dn')
      | list
      }}
```

You would only want those `map('from_json')` call if your data structure contained **embedded** JSON, like so:

```
- set_fact:
     inner_value: >-
        {{ (example_text | from_json).a_key
        | map("from_json")
        | map(attribute="inner_key")
        | list
        }}
  vars:
    example_text: |
      {"a_key": ["{\"inner_key\": \"inner value\"}"]}
```

Comment: Could please guide me for the above JSON? within array I have another JSON which is where I confused as I am relatively new to ansible

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). For example the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ nodes.imdata|
                 json_query('[].{dn: fabricNode.attributes.dn,
                                 name: fabricNode.attributes.name}')
                                 }}"
- debug:
    var: my_list
```

give

```
"my_list": [
    {
        "dn": "topology/pod-1/node-1", 
        "name": "NOQCJALAB1"
    }, 
    {
        "dn": "topology/pod-1/node-1", 
        "name": "NOQCJALAB2"
    }
]
```

Comment: simple superb! thanks lot. can we have a simply json instead json array?

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I will post appropriate going forward as I am not able to edit in detail now. Json array looks ok. thanks lot

Comment: Hello,  could you please guide me if you have one more array within imdata ? array within array